# Populate 1 dataframe based on values in another

Tags: pandas

I am trying to append values into a new pandas dataframe (df_t2) by looping over df. Assign does not seem to work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

```
values = {'No': ['123','456'],
        'data1': [22000,25000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['No', 'data1'])
```

Code to loop over dataframe (df) and copy it to df_t2:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df_t2["No"] = row['No']
   df_t2[str(row['point1']) = row['data1']
```

Comment: You should add a minimum working example including code to generate your dataframes and code showing your desired output.

Comment: @DocBuckets: I have edited the code.

Comment: You should have a clear example of what the output should be, it is very hard to understand what are you trying to do. - 'point1' does not even exist, check if your example code even run..

Comment: I think you need `merge` with left join

Comment: or `map` if need join by one column

Answer (score 0):

Try reading here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```py
import pandas as pd
values = {'No1': ['123','4562'], 'data1': [22000,21000] }

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(values , columns = ['No1', 'data1'])

values = {'No2': ['1231','456'], 'data2': [24000,25000] }
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(values , columns = ['No2', 'data2'])

all_values = np.concatenate([df_1.values,df_2.values])
new_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(all_values, columns = df_2.columns)
```

Comment: Its not a direct copy, column names are different in both

Comment: Mayeb this? @user3447653